# Firestore: find document in nested collections

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have these collections:

```
users/portfolios/rents/events
```

How could I find events with title `Lunch`?

I need to search for all users, portfolios, rents and events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to query across all `events` collections in your entire database, you'll want to use a so-called [Collection Group Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

Comment: In those examples I see we always select a specific document for the cities collection. What about if I'm interested in all documents? Do I need to create a composite index as explained here? https://firebase.blog/posts/2019/06/understanding-collection-group-queries

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that first part, but: yes, you always need to explicitly create the index required for a collection group query, as auto-generated indexes are always specific for a collection (not across all collections of the same name).

Comment: I mean if that's necessary to perform the query correctly

Comment: Also, in terms of performance and probably plan limitation, would it be better to move the events to a separated collection outside of users? So I would have for each event userId, porfolioId and rentsId as well

Comment: I'm going to open a separate question for this. Thanks for the original answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73335166/firebase-performance-vs-plan-quota-limitations