# Firebase: Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation's execution

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm starting working with collections groups in Firebase and I cannot make it work. I need to filter it by `billable` leases:

```
users/portfolios/rents
```

Here I have a property which is a list of leases (not a collection, just a property) called `leases` with some properties like `billable`:

[image]

I have created a single-field index:

[image]

And also a composite index (not sure if I also need it):

[image]

This is my query using Flutter:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collectionGroup('rents')
        .where('billable', isEqualTo: true)
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      for (var doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
        print(doc);
      }
    });
```

The error I get is:

> Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation's execution. If performing a query, ensure it has been indexed via the Firebase console.

It's not indexed already?

Comment: Can you append `?hl=en` to the URL of your console and repost the screenshots with that, so that they show up in English?

Comment: done. Not sure why it was displayed with mixed languages

Comment: I enabled Arrays option in 1st screenshot and I'm not getting this issue now but not sure why I don't get any document with .collectionGroup('rents')
        .where(
          'leases',
          arrayContains: {'billable': true},
        )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the query in your question you'll need a collection group index on the `finished` field of the `rents` collection group, which I don't see in any of the screenshots you shared.

---

From the screenshot of a document you linked in the comments here:

[image]

So `billable` is a value in each item of the `leases` array field. There is no way to query on such a single value in an array field, as the `==` operator checks whether the entire array field is the same as the value you specify, and the `arrayContains` operator checks if any array item matches the entire value you specify.

The common workaround is to extra the value you want to query on to a top-level field, either an array field or a single boolean. For example, if you add a field `hasAnyBillableLeases` to the `rents` document, you can query on that.

Alternatively, put the `leases` in their own subcollection, so that each lease becomes its own document and then can then query its `billable` field.

Comment: Still the same error. I updated the 2nd screenshot with the field now (I updated from finished to billable btw. I need to really calculate some dates but in order to make it simpler I made it up. Billable is something that I don't need but I really have, just for the screenshots now)

Comment: should it be "For queries within a specific collection path"?

Comment: Also, where do I specify the field leases? Rents is the collection and leases just a list of objects where we have this billable property. So the composite index (2nd image) is wrong I guess

Comment: I still don't see an index on the `rents` collection **group** in the screenshots you shared. You don't need a composite index here (as you're only filtering on one field), but you do need to define an index on the `billable` field of the `rents` collection **group**.

Comment: You mean like this?
https://ibb.co/px107cz
https://ibb.co/Ctf7S22
If so where should I specify that billable is inside leases and not inside rent?

Comment: Aha! So `leases` is an array field in each document under `rents`. That is something that'd have been useful to see in the question, so I recommend adding the screenshot of the document there. --- There is unfortunately no way to create an index on that specific item in an array field. I added an explanation of the common workaround.

Comment: I had that: "Here I have a property which is a list of leases (not a collection, just a property) called leases with some properties like billable."

Comment: The problem with that workaround is that if I need extra filters in the future I'll need to change all of them again or add extra fields. 
What is the array scope option for?

Comment: Also this creates an extra dependency. Every time I update the leases I'll need to update the rent. I guess this would affect the billing plan having to write twice.

Probably better to take out the leases and move them to a new collection outside of everything and leave only leases=['id1', 'id2'...] in rents.

Would be that easier to perform these queries?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to say that in my answer: consider making the array items into another subcollection, so you can query on *that*.

Comment: feel free to also add that. I'll accept it since this type of query is not possible and I'll try to take out any kind of collection. Makes everything much easier